# Upgrading / Downgrading to a different version of plex package

Tags: apt, software-installation, plex

How can I upgrade / downgrade to a different package version of plex

**I can see what's upgradable by typing in.**

1. pi@pistorage:~ $ `sudo apt list --upgradable`

```
Listing... Done

plexmediaserver/public 1.22.1.4228-724c56e62 armhf [upgradable from: 1.22.0.4163-d8c4875dd]
N: There are **13 additional versions. Please use the '-a'** switch to see them.
```

**I can see the versions by typing in.**

2. pi@pistorage:~ $ `sudo apt list --upgradable -a`

```
plexmediaserver/public 1.22.1.4228-724c56e62 armhf [upgradable from: 1.22.0.4163-d8c4875dd]
plexmediaserver/public,now 1.22.0.4163-d8c4875dd armhf [installed,upgradable to: 1.22.1.4228-724c56e62]
plexmediaserver/public 1.21.4.4079-1b7748a7b armhf
plexmediaserver/public 1.21.3.4046-3c1c83ba4 armhf
plexmediaserver/public 1.21.3.4021-5a0a3e4b2 armhf
plexmediaserver/public 1.21.3.4015-a4be9cb8b armhf
plexmediaserver/public 1.21.3.4014-58bd20c02 armhf
plexmediaserver/public 1.21.2.3943-a91458577 armhf
plexmediaserver/public 1.21.2.3939-3945797bd armhf
plexmediaserver/public 1.21.1.3876-3c3adfcb4 armhf
plexmediaserver/public 1.21.1.3842-b0c7a97d9 armhf
plexmediaserver/public 1.21.1.3830-6c22540d5 armhf
plexmediaserver/public 1.21.1.3795-ee64ab56f armhf
plexmediaserver/public 1.21.1.3766-7e23ef53c armhf
```

**How can I choose the exact version to install? (Plex upgrades have a tendency to break things during upgrades)**

I know I can use `sudo apt --only-upgrade install plexmediaserver`

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-upgrade-update-single-package-using-apt-get/

**I'm just not sure how to pick the exact one I want.**

Comment: See `man apt` for how to specify a target version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sudo systemctl stop plexmediaserver`
2. `cd  /var/cache/apt/archives`
3. `sudo apt install ./plexmediaserver_1.22.0.4163-d8c4875dd_armhf.deb`
4. **may not be needed in changes for user / pwd** `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service`

-`Then reboot server`

5. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
6. 

**For testing:**

```
sudo systemctl restart plexmediaserver
sudo service plexmediaserver status
sudo systemctl restart plexmediaserver
sudo systemctl stop plexmediaserver
sudo systemctl start plexmediaserver
```